# Create labels in form and update them from background threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a number of background threads (in this case 5) that generated like the code below:

```
 Progress prog = new Progress();
 foreach (var questionLang in QuestionsLangConstants.questionLangs.Values)
 {
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
   delegate
   {
    qrepo.UploadQuestions(QWorkBook.Worksheets[questionLang.QSheet], questionLang, prog);
   });
 }
 prog.Show();
```

`Progress` is a form that has the following code in it.

```
private delegate Label AddNewLabel();
private delegate void ChangeLabelText(Label lbl, string text);


    public Label addNewLabel()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AddNewLabel adl = new AddNewLabel(addNewLabel);
            this.Invoke(adl);
            return new Label();
        }
        else
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();

            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            return lbl;
        }
    }

    public void changeLabelText(Label lbl, string text)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ChangeLabelText clt = new ChangeLabelText(changeLabelText);
            this.Invoke(clt, new object[] { lbl, text });

        }
        else
        {

            lbl.Text = text;

        }
    }
```

And the `UploadQuestions` function reads and excel file and uses

```
 Label lbl = prog.addNewLabel();
 while (questionNum != "")
 {
    //code here
    prog.changeLabelText(lbl, questionNum);
   //code to increment questionNum

 }
```

I would expect that 5 labels would be created and updated with the number of rows in the excel but nothing happens. The labels are not updated but are created. (even on over the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this method "public Label addNewLabel()" in the if statement after invoking the delegate, you are returning a new label and not the original label that is created in the else statement. Not very sure if this is the problem though.

EDIT:

Instead of "this.Invoke(adl);" try "return (this.Invoke(adl) as Label);" and remove "return new Label();" statement.

Comment: I've thought about it but I cannot think of a way to circumvent the need for returning a value from every path in the method. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Not very sure if this will help but instead of "this.Invoke(adl);" can you try "this.Controls.Add((this.Invoke(adl) as Control));" or maybe "return (this.Invoke(adl) as Control);" and remove "return new Label();" statement?

Comment: Did you tried the second solution as well in the above comment which I made? The first solution is wrong, i agree. My bad.

Comment: this solved the problem. Just instead of as Control I had to use as Label. Thank you very much. Just to make sure I get it... I trick the method in thinking that I am returning a Label right? Can you please add it to your answer above so as to mark it as correct and upvote it?

Comment: Actually you were returning a new object of label after adding it to the form and that new object's text was getting set and not the one which was getting added to the form. Glad I could be of some help.